# can we use character value in priority queue?

Tags: c, linked-list, priority-queue

Can we use character priorities like 'h' for high or 'l' for low in this case and use it to implement a priority queue?

```
struct node {
int data;
char c;
struct node *next;
};
```

Comment: Yes. Since characters are encoded as numbers (so you are still using numbers to prioritize, it just isn't necessarily sequential). But I don't see the benefit.

Comment: Yes, you can, just define your own cmp function(or operator<)

Comment: can you provide me with a sample code on how we can implement the queue in this case ?

Comment: @SaM, This isn't how SO works. If you try something, and reach a deadened, the community will be happy to assist you in most cases. But we won't write the code from scratch for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can do that. I assume you simply want to use meaningful names for the priorities rather than magic numbers.

You may want to consider using an enum:

```
enum QueuePriority 
{
  HIGH,
  MEDUIM,
  LOW
};

struct node
{
  int data;
  enum QueuePriority priority;
  struct node *next;
};
```

This has the benefit of not having to create a custom comparison function/operator. Since the built-in will do as long as the enum values are in the right order.
(I have them with `HIGH == 0` as is the convention in some systems, but you can easily reverse that).